# GentleSelect : align center relative to the select box

Tags: jquery, css

I use plugin '[gentleSelect](http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-gentleSelect/)' (multi column dropdownliast), by default list is right-aligned. 
how to make the list (more column) centered relative to the select box

with original configuration :

```
              page
              1  2   3    4   5
              6  7   8    9   10
              ....
```

I want like this :

```
                        page
                  1  2   3    4   5
                  6  7   8    9   10
                  ....
```

**html**

```
<div id="page" align="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page_sel').gentleSelect({ 
            columns: 18,
            itemWidth: 4,
            title: "الصفحة",
            hideOnMouseOut: true
        });


});
</script>
<select id="page_sel" style="display: none;" >
<?php 
for($i=1;$i<=604;$i++){
?>
<option id="<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if(....) {echo "selected";}?> ><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php }//end for page?>
</select>
</div>
```

jquery-gentleSelect.css :

```
.gentleselect-data { display: none; }

.gentleselect-label {
    padding: 1px 20px 1px 20px;
    background-color: #eee;

    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;   

    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center right; 

    cursor: pointer;
    color: #555;
}

.gentleselect-label-highlight {
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background-image: url('img/expand.png');
}

.gentleselect-dialog {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    display: none;

    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #999;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #555;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #555;

    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.gentleselect-dialog > ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style: none; }
.gentleselect-dialog > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 25px;

    cursor: pointer;
}
.gentleselect-dialog > ul > li.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #369;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.gentleselect-dialog > ul > li.gentleselect-dummy:hover { background-color: #fff; }
.gentleselect-dialog > ul > li:hover {
    background-color: #69c;
    color: #fff;
}

.gentleselect-dialog > .gentleselect-title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #666;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jquery-gentleSelect.js :

```
(function($) {

var defaults = {
    minWidth  : 100, // only applies if columns and itemWidth not set
    itemWidth : undefined,
    columns   : undefined,
    rows      : undefined,
    title     : undefined,
    prompt    : "Make A Selection",
    maxDisplay: 0,  // set to 0 for unlimited
    openSpeed       : 400,
    closeSpeed      : 400,
    openEffect      : "slide",
    closeEffect     : "slide",
    hideOnMouseOut  : true
}

function defined(obj) {
    if (typeof obj == "undefined") { return false; }
    else { return true; }
}

function hasError(c, o) {
    if (defined(o.columns) && defined(o.rows)) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: You cannot supply both 'rows' and 'columns'");
        return true;
    }
    if (defined(o.columns) && !defined(o.itemWidth)) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: itemWidth must be supplied if 'columns' is specified");
        return true;
    }
    if (defined(o.rows) && !defined(o.itemWidth)) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: itemWidth must be supplied if 'rows' is specified");
        return true;
    }
    if (!defined(o.openSpeed) || typeof o.openSpeed != "number" && 
            (typeof o.openSpeed == "string" && (o.openSpeed != "slow" && o.openSpeed != "fast"))) { 
        $.error("gentleSelect: openSpeed must be an integer or \"slow\" or \"fast\"");
        return true;
    }
    if (!defined(o.closeSpeed) || typeof o.closeSpeed != "number" && 
            (typeof o.closeSpeed == "string" && (o.closeSpeed != "slow" && o.closeSpeed != "fast"))) { 
        $.error("gentleSelect: closeSpeed must be an integer or \"slow\" or \"fast\"");
        return true;
    }
    if (!defined(o.openEffect) || (o.openEffect != "fade" && o.openEffect != "slide")) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: openEffect must be either 'fade' or 'slide'!");
        return true;
    }
    if (!defined(o.closeEffect)|| (o.closeEffect != "fade" && o.closeEffect != "slide")) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: closeEffect must be either 'fade' or 'slide'!");
        return true;
    }
    if (!defined(o.hideOnMouseOut) || (typeof o.hideOnMouseOut != "boolean")) {
        $.error("gentleSelect: hideOnMouseOut must be supplied and either \"true\" or \"false\"!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function optionOverrides(c, o) {
    if (c.attr("multiple")) {
        o.hideOnMouseOut = true; // must be true or dialog will never hide
    }
}

function getSelectedAsText(elemList, opts) { 
    // If no items selected, return prompt
    if (elemList.length < 1) { return opts.prompt; }

    // Truncate if exceed maxDisplay
    if (opts.maxDisplay != 0 && elemList.length > opts.maxDisplay) {
        var arr = elemList.slice(0, opts.maxDisplay).map(function(){return $(this).text();});
        arr.push("...");
    } else {
        var arr = elemList.map(function(){return $(this).text();});
    }
    return arr.get().join(", ");
}

var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
        var o = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if (hasError(this, o)) { return this; }; // check for errors
        optionOverrides(this, o); // 
        this.hide(); // hide original select box

        // initialise <span> to replace select box
        label_text = getSelectedAsText(this.find(":selected"), o);
        var label = $("<span class='gentleselect-label'>" + label_text + "</span>")
            .insertBefore(this)
            .bind("mouseenter.gentleselect", event_handlers.labelHoverIn)
            .bind("mouseleave.gentleselect", event_handlers.labelHoverOut)
            .bind("click.gentleselect", event_handlers.labelClick)
            .data("root", this);
        this.data("label", label)
            .data("options", o);

        // generate list of options
        var ul = $("<ul></ul>");
        this.find("option").each(function() { 
            var li = $("<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>")
                .data("value", $(this).attr("value"))
                .data("name", $(this).text())
                .appendTo(ul);
            if ($(this).attr("selected")) { li.addClass("selected"); } 
        });

        // build dialog box
        var dialog = $("<div class='gentleselect-dialog'></div>")
            .append(ul)
            .insertAfter(label)
            .bind("click.gentleselect", event_handlers.dialogClick)
            .bind("mouseleave.gentleselect", event_handlers.dialogHoverOut)
            .data("label", label)
            .data("root", this);
        this.data("dialog", dialog);

        // if to be displayed in columns
        if (defined(o.columns) || defined(o.rows)) {

            // Update CSS
            ul.css("float", "left")
                .find("li").width(o.itemWidth).css("float","left");

            var f = ul.find("li:first");
            var actualWidth = o.itemWidth 
                + parseInt(f.css("padding-left")) 
                + parseInt(f.css("padding-right"));
            var elemCount = ul.find("li").length;
            if (defined(o.columns)) {
                var cols = parseInt(o.columns);
                var rows = Math.ceil(elemCount / cols);
            } else {
                var rows = parseInt(o.rows);
                var cols = Math.ceil(elemCount / rows);
            }
            dialog.width(actualWidth * cols);

            // add padding
            for (var i = 0; i < (rows * cols) - elemCount; i++) {
                $("<li style='float:left' class='gentleselect-dummy'><span>&nbsp;</span></li>").appendTo(ul);
            }

            // reorder elements
            var ptr = [];
            var idx = 0;
            ul.find("li").each(function() {
                if (idx < rows) { 
                    ptr[idx] = $(this); 
                } else {
                    var p = idx % rows;
                    $(this).insertAfter(ptr[p]);
                    ptr[p] = $(this);
                }
                idx++;
            });
        } else if (typeof o.minWidth == "number") {
            dialog.css("min-width", o.minWidth);
        }

        if (defined(o.title)) {
            $("<div class='gentleselect-title'>" + o.title + "</div>").prependTo(dialog);
        }

        // ESC key should hide all dialog boxes
        $(document).bind("keyup.gentleselect", event_handlers.keyUp);

        return this;
    },

    // if select box was updated externally, we need to bring everything
    // else up to speed.
    update : function() {
        var opts = this.data("options");

        // Update li with selected data
        var v = (this.attr("multiple")) ? this.val() : [this.val()];
        $("li", this.data("dialog")).each(function() {
            var $li = $(this);
            var isSelected = ($.inArray($li.data("value"), v) != -1);
            $li.toggleClass("selected", isSelected);
        });

        // Update label
        var label = getSelectedAsText(this.find(":selected"), opts);
        this.data("label").text(label);

        return this;
    }
};

var event_handlers = {

    labelHoverIn : function() { 
        $(this).addClass('gentleselect-label-highlight'); 
    },

    labelHoverOut : function() { 
        $(this).removeClass('gentleselect-label-highlight'); 
    },

    labelClick : function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var pos = $this.position();
        var root = $this.data("root");
        var opts = root.data("options");
        var dialog = root.data("dialog")
            .css("top", pos.top + $this.height())
            .css("left", pos.left + 1);
        if (opts.openEffect == "fade") {
            dialog.fadeIn(opts.openSpeed);
        } else {
            dialog.slideDown(opts.openSpeed);
        }
    },

    dialogHoverOut : function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data("root").data("options").hideOnMouseOut) {
            $this.hide();
        }
    },

    dialogClick : function(e) {
        var clicked = $(e.target);
        var $this = $(this);
        var root = $this.data("root");
        var opts = root.data("options");
        if (!root.attr("multiple")) {
            if (opts.closeEffect == "fade") {
                $this.fadeOut(opts.closeSpeed);
            } else {
                $this.slideUp(opts.closeSpeed);
            }
        }

        if (clicked.is("li") && !clicked.hasClass("gentleselect-dummy")) {
            var value = clicked.data("value");
            var name = clicked.data("name");
            var label = $this.data("label")

            if ($this.data("root").attr("multiple")) {
                clicked.toggleClass("selected");
                var s = $this.find("li.selected");
                label.text(getSelectedAsText(s, opts));
                var v = s.map(function(){ return $(this).data("value"); });
                // update actual selectbox and trigger change event
                root.val(v.get()).trigger("change");
            } else {
                $this.find("li.selected").removeClass("selected");
                clicked.addClass("selected");
                label.text(clicked.data("name"));
                // update actual selectbox and trigger change event
                root.val(value).trigger("change");
            }
        }
    },

    keyUp : function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 ) { // ESC
            $(".gentleselect-dialog").hide();
        }
    }
};

$.fn.gentleSelect = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.gentleSelect' );
    }   
};


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please post related CSS and HTML

Comment: align it center dragging both eyes ^_^.

Comment: Change CSS class accordingly. '.gentleselect-dialog > ul > li'

Comment: I want to change the left value(calculated from 'jquery-gentleSelect.js' ) of gentleselect-dialog. I have added 'margin-left:-200px' in style of  gentleselect-dialog it works In google chrome but not in firefox. how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem , by adding one line in jquery-gentleSelect.css:

```
.gentleselect-dialog {
   ....

    margin: 0px 0px 0px -240px; /* old margin : 0px */
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a custom CSS style to the `<li>` element, which is currently set to `text-align: left`. Write something like:

```
.gentleselect-dialog ul li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin as well. I have the same problem. As a temporary solution, you can change the property `left`:

```
var dialog = root.data("dialog")
             .css("top", pos.top + $this.height())
             .css("left", pos.left + 1);
```

Change `pos.left + 1` with the number of your choice (in pixels) or replace `left` with `right`.

In my jquery-gentleSelect.css I have:

```
var dialog = root.data("dialog")
             //~ .css("top", pos.top + $this.height())
             .css("right", 50);
```

Good luck!